CORS failure accessing ASP.NET Core 8 Web API hosted in Azure from localhost
I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API, hosted in Azure. It works fine when everything is deployed to Azure. But we are trying to run a Reactjs front end locally and access that Web API in Azure for testing and debugging. I have followed all the docs about setting up CORS on the web service, but keep getting:

Access to fetch at 'https:///api/stats' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            policy => {
                     policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowCredentials();
                  });
    });

builder.Services
       .AddControllers()
       .AddJsonOptions(x =>
            {
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
            });

Then, later on, after doing var app = builder.Build()
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers()
             .RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "client-app";
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer("start");
    }
});

I've even tried adding [EnableCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins)] to the controller itself.
This is for an open source project for a non-profit. Hoping someone knows the solution. Any ideas?
Here is the Program.cs in its entirety:
https://github.com/TrashMob-eco/TrashMob/blob/main/TrashMob/Program.cs
I have tried changing order of statement, tried old approaches and new from searches, tried opening up all origins. Nothing seems to work.

Have you checked in your azure portal's   CORS settings where you should have  'http://localhost:3000` as an allowed origin. Apart from this your code seems correct.

I literally just found this setting... that was exactly it!

Okay, Glad to know that it resolved our issue.

The site is hosted in an Azure Web App, and inside the web app settings, under the "API" submenu, there is an entry called CORS. I added a record there for http://localhost:3000 and everything worked.


